# Locked in standalone mode, can't refresh the manifest file

Tags: iphone, web-applications, manifest

I tried the standalone mode for a web application in the `manifest.json` file, but the iPhone just opens Safari to display the website. So I didn't found this option very useful. I put the application back in the browser mode, but no effect, when clicking on the icon it is opened as standalone. So here is it a local cache issue only ? Can test on https://tokeeen.com

```
{
 "doc": "https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Manifest",
 "version": "0.10.1",
 "name": "",
 "short_name": "Tokeeen",
 "lang": "en",
 "background_color": "#000000",
 "display": "browser",
 "scope": "/",
 "start_url": "./?utm_source=manifest",
 "splash_screens": [],
 "icons": [
  {
   "src": "\/android-icon-36x36.png",
   "sizes": "36x36",
   "type": "image\/png",
   "density": "0.75"
  },
  {
   "src": "\/android-icon-48x48.png",
   "sizes": "48x48",
   "type": "image\/png",
   "density": "1.0"
  },
  {
   "src": "\/android-icon-72x72.png",
   "sizes": "72x72",
   "type": "image\/png",
   "density": "1.5"
  },
  {
   "src": "\/android-icon-96x96.png",
   "sizes": "96x96",
   "type": "image\/png",
   "density": "2.0"
  },
  {
   "src": "\/android-icon-144x144.png",
   "sizes": "144x144",
   "type": "image\/png",
   "density": "3.0"
  },
  {
   "src": "\/android-icon-192x192.png",
   "sizes": "192x192",
   "type": "image\/png",
   "density": "4.0"
  }
 ]
}
```